# How to make a vertical line in R

Tags: r, normal-distribution

```
curve(dnorm(x,90,10),from=60, to=120)
```

I need to make some vertical line in the x line that in number 70 and 110.

How should I do it?

[image]

Comment: I'd use `segments` to set 2 or more line segments. See `?segments`.

Answer (score 2):

From your picture, you don't want a line extending across the whole plot, as `abline`, but instead want a line extending just to the point of the curve.

```
lines(c(70,70),c(0, dnorm(70, 90, 10)))
```

The two vectors define the endpoints in x and the endpoints in y, respectively.

Comment: Question seems on-topic as it is about data visualization.  I'd like to see a fuller explanation for the effective code described by @user777.